I prepared a bash script to run in terminal in Almalinux but it stucks at -type d step
I have prepared a bash script which will help me clear cache, views and routes in laravel under 400+ folders. i have also added to skip the fodlers which does not have laravel fodler structure.
All the folders reside under home folder.
The websites are hosted in ALmalinux VPS.
The script halts at step -type d after it finds all the folders and does not go after wards.
ANy help in this regard is appreciated.
I tried to run the following script
#!/bin/bash

# Log file location
log_file="$HOME/auto_clear_caches.log"

# Initialize or clear the log file
echo "Starting cache clearing process..." > "$log_file"

# Find all public_html directories under /home and store them in an array
website_folders=$(find /home/*/public_html -type d 2>/dev/null)

# Check if the find command found any directories
if [ -z "$website_folders" ]; then
    echo "No public_html directories found under /home." >> "$log_file"
    exit 1
fi

# Iterate through each found directory
for target_dir in $website_folders; do
    # Check if the directory exists
    if [ -d "$target_dir" ]; then
        echo "Checking $target_dir..." >> "$log_file"

        # Check for Laravel-specific files/directories
        if [ -f "$target_dir/artisan" ] && [ -d "$target_dir/app" ] && [ -d "$target_dir/config" ]; then
            echo "Navigating to $target_dir..." >> "$log_file"
            cd "$target_dir" || { echo "Failed to navigate to $target_dir" >> "$log_file"; exit 1; }

            # Clear caches and capture the output
            {
                echo "Clearing application cache..."
                php artisan cache:clear

                echo "Clearing event cache..."
                php artisan event:clear

                echo "Clearing route cache..."
                php artisan route:clear

                echo "Clearing view cache..."
                php artisan view:clear

                echo "Clearing config cache..."
                php artisan config:clear

                echo "All caches cleared successfully in $target_dir!"
            } >> "$log_file" 2>&1

            # Return to the home directory
            cd ~ || { echo "Failed to return to the home directory" >> "$log_file"; exit 1; }
        else
            echo "$target_dir does not have a typical Laravel structure. Skipping..." >> "$log_file"
        fi
    else
        echo "Directory $target_dir does not exist." >> "$log_file"
    fi
done

echo "Script completed. Exiting..." >> "$log_file"

BUt it halts at the following step and does not write the log file also
[root@hhhhhh home]# bash -x rundirectories.sh

log_file=/root/auto_clear_caches.log
echo 'Starting cache clearing process...'
++ find /home/1evisac/public_html /home/albania/public_html /home/anhostel/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/anytimeh/public_html /home/anytime/public_html /home/anytimet/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/anytimho/public_html /home/appeala/public_html /home/appoint/public                                                                                        html /home/appwebs/public_html /home/arbeite/public_html /home/ausbild/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/ausbildv/public_html /home/austral/public_html /home/austriaw/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/bangla24/public_html /home/belgiumw/public_html /home/bengalicrime/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/bengalif/public_html /home/bengalipress/public_html /home/bestevi                                                                                        /public_html /home/bhaluka/public_html /home/bharate/public_html /home/bookmyl/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/brandmegashop/public_html /home/brandsmega/public_html /home/br                                                                                        others/public_html /home/brysona/public_html /home/bulgaria/public_html /home/bu                                                                                        sinese/public_html /home/call4ton/public_html /home/call4to/public_html /home/ca                                                                                        ll4tos/public_html /home/calltour/public_html /home/calltri/public_html /home/ca                                                                                        reerp/public_html /home/caregiv/public_html /home/champio/public_html /home/chan                                                                                        cen/public_html /home/citizens/public_html /home/collageb/public_html /home/coll                                                                                        agec/public_html /home/collagenfactory/public_html /home/collagep/public_html /h                                                                                        ome/collagex/public_html /home/collagwa/public_html /home/collagwo/public_html /                                                                                        home/countrya/public_html /home/countrypolicy/public_html /home/criminal/public                                                                                        html /home/croatia/public_html /home/cyprusw/public_html /home/czechrep/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/daily/public_html /home/denmark/public_html /home/doctora/public_html                                                                                         /home/doctorte/public_html /home/ecentre/public_html /home/echecker/public_html                                                                                         /home/eclick/public_html /home/econnect/public_html /home/ecountry/public_html /                                                                                        home/ecroatia/public_html /home/ecyprus/public_html /home/edaily/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/edenmark/public_html /home/edocumen/public_html /home/eearth/public_html /hom                                                                                        e/eembassy/public_html /home/efinland/public_html /home/efortune/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/egerman/public_html /home/egermany/public_html /home/egreece/public_html /hom                                                                                        e/egroup/public_html /home/ehelp/public_html /home/ehistory/public_html /home/eh                                                                                        oliday/public_html /home/ejakarta/public_html /home/ejapan/public_html /home/ejo                                                                                        bs/public_html /home/ejobsre/public_html /home/ekingdom/public_html /home/ekosov                                                                                        o/public_html /home/ekuwait/public_html /home/elatvia/public_html /home/electio/                                                                                        public_html /home/electric/public_html /home/electro/public_html /home/emalaysi/                                                                                        public_html /home/emaldive/public_html /home/emalta/public_html /home/emanager/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/emontene/public_html /home/enetwork/public_html /home/enorway/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/entryev/public_html /home/eoffice/public_html /home/eofficer/pu                                                                                        blic_html /home/epartner/public_html /home/epayment/public_html /home/eperu/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/ephillip/public_html /home/epoland/public_html /home/eproblem/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/erequire/public_html /home/eresult/public_html /home/ereview/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/ereviews/public_html /home/eromania/public_html /home/escamme/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/escotlan/public_html /home/eservic/public_html /home/esingapo/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/eskorea/public_html /home/esolutio/public_html /home/estatus/public                                                                                        html /home/estonia/public_html /home/estudent/public_html /home/esubmiss/public                                                                                        html /home/esuccess/public_html /home/esuperm/public_html /home/esweden/public                                                                                        html /home/eswissb/public_html /home/etaiwand/public_html /home/eticket/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/etravell/public_html /home/eunotec/public_html /home/euroboo/public_ht                                                                                        ml /home/europea/public_html /home/evacatio/public_html /home/evday/public_html                                                                                         /home/evenezue/public_html /home/evgate/public_html /home/evhungar/public_html /                                                                                        home/evisaab/public_html /home/evisaac/public_html /home/evisaad/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/evisaag/public_html /home/evisaai/public_html /home/evisaan/public_html /home                                                                                        /evisaap/public_html /home/evisaaps/public_html /home/evisaar/public_html /home/                                                                                        evisaas/public_html /home/evisaau/public_html /home/evisaba/public_html /home/ev                                                                                        isabe/public_html /home/evisabg/public_html /home/evisabh/public_html /home/evis                                                                                        abhu/public_html /home/evisabl/public_html /home/evisaboo/public_html /home/evis                                                                                        ace/public_html /home/evisaem/public_html /home/evisain/public_html /home/evkoso                                                                                        vo/public_html /home/evlive/public_html /home/evpoint/public_html /home/evroad/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/evstate/public_html /home/evstory/public_html /home/evsubmit/pu                                                                                        blic_html /home/evtoday/public_html /home/evtours/public_html /home/evtravel/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/evupdate/public_html /home/evweb/public_html /home/evwork/public                                                                                        html /home/evzone/public_html /home/eworkper/public_html /home/factoryc/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/familye/public_html /home/fastevi/public_html /home/firstev/public_htm                                                                                        l /home/francew/public_html /home/fraudsc/public_html /home/garmen34/public_html                                                                                         /home/germanex/public_html /home/germanyt/public_html /home/germanyw/public_htm                                                                                        l /home/globalv/public_html /home/governm/public_html /home/greecew/public_html                                                                                         /home/honeybd/public_html /home/honeygro/public_html /home/honeymo/public_html /                                                                                        home/honeytt/public_html /home/hospita/public_html /home/hospite/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/hungarye/public_html /home/hungaryw/public_html /home/inovatiq/public_html /h                                                                                        ome/italywor/public_html /home/japanwo/public_html /home/jobdema/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/joboffe/public_html /home/jobperm/public_html /home/jobssca/public_html /home                                                                                        /jobsseek/public_html /home/jubodal/public_html /home/kanaksa/public_html /home/                                                                                        kidsted/public_html /home/kosovow/public_html /home/krankter/public_html /home/l                                                                                        ajjatv/public_html /home/lastvis/public_html /home/latviaw/public_html /home/lis                                                                                        bont/public_html /home/madridt/public_html /home/medi24/public_html /home/mediaw                                                                                        ar/public_html /home/medical2/public_html /home/medicalt/public_html /home/medil                                                                                        imi/public_html /home/medisupp/public_html /home/mediterm/public_html /home/mold                                                                                        ova/public_html /home/monteneg/public_html /home/morthmac/public_html /home/mult                                                                                        iev/public_html /home/myfunto/public_html /home/mymensi/public_html /home/newzea                                                                                        l/public_html /home/nextevi/public_html /home/norwaywk/public_html /home/novisan                                                                                        /public_html /home/onlinev/public_html /home/ordervis/public_html /home/pakistan                                                                                        /public_html /home/polandw/public_html /home/politic2/public_html /home/popularv                                                                                        /public_html /home/portugal/public_html /home/priority/public_html /home/prothom                                                                                        /public_html /home/rajuahm/public_html /home/rightway/public_html /home/romania/                                                                                        public_html /home/rometou/public_html /home/scheng24/public_html /home/secrett/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/serbiaw/public_html /home/sexycon/public_html /home/simamot/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/singera/public_html /home/singlev/public_html /home/skilledw/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/skilljo/public_html /home/skillwo/public_html /home/skincar/public                                                                                        _html /home/slovakia/public_html /home/slovenia/public_html /home/somewhej/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/southko/public_html /home/studentv/public_html /home/studyvi/public                                                                                        html /home/successf/public_html /home/swedenw/public_html /home/switzerl/public                                                                                        html /home/takabook/public_html /home/takacash/public_html /home/thecolla/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/thedemo/public_html /home/theevisa/public_html /home/tourawad/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/tourista/public_html /home/touristu/public_html /home/typesofv/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/ukilchai/public_html /home/unitedki/public_html /home/vasylum/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/visaaff/public_html /home/visaagri/public_html /home/visaappl/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/visaapro/public_html /home/visaawad/public_html /home/visaboar/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/visacalc/public_html /home/visacall/public_html /home/visacane/pu                                                                                        blic_html /home/visacast/public_html /home/visacate/public_html /home/visacat/pu                                                                                        blic_html /home/visacave/public_html /home/visachec/public_html /home/visacloc/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/visacoa/public_html /home/visacola/public_html /home/visacoll/p                                                                                        ublic_html /home/visacolr/public_html /home/visacomd/public_html /home/visacomm/                                                                                        public_html /home/visacoms/public_html /home/visacond/public_html /home/visacons                                                                                        /public_html /home/visacont/public_html /home/visaconv/public_html /home/visacoo                                                                                        r/public_html /home/visacord/public_html /home/visacorr/public_html /home/visaco                                                                                        ur/public_html /home/visacrui/public_html /home/visacust/public_html /home/visad                                                                                        ail/public_html /home/visadiar/public_html /home/visadura/public_html /home/visa                                                                                        edit/public_html /home/visafax/public_html /home/visafeed/public_html /home/visa                                                                                        fery/public_html /home/visaffil/public_html /home/visafold/public_html /home/vis                                                                                        agovr/public_html /home/visaheav/public_html /home/visahigh/public_html /home/vi                                                                                        sahigw/public_html /home/visahumn/public_html /home/visaimm/public_html /home/vi                                                                                        saimpo/public_html /home/visaindu/public_html /home/visainfo/public_html /home/v                                                                                        isainpt/public_html /home/visainq/public_html /home/visainsr/public_html /home/v                                                                                        isainst/public_html /home/visaissr/public_html /home/visaissu/public_html /home/                                                                                        visakoso/public_html /home/visalamp/public_html /home/visalean/public_html /home                                                                                        /visamald/public_html /home/visamana/public_html /home/visamond/public_html /hom                                                                                        e/visamont/public_html /home/visamore/public_html /home/visamuse/public_html /ho                                                                                        me/visaneed/public_html /home/visanews/public_html /home/visanigt/public_html /h                                                                                        ome/visanobl/public_html /home/visanote/public_html /home/visaoffi/public_html /                                                                                        home/visaoffr/public_html /home/visaopen/public_html /home/visaoutc/public_html                                                                                         /home/visapapa/public_html /home/visapenc/public_html /home/visapoin/public_html                                                                                         /home/visaprac/public_html /home/visaprce/public_html /home/visaprec/public_htm                                                                                        l /home/visapres/public_html /home/visapri/public_html /home/visaproc/public_htm                                                                                        l /home/visaprof/public_html /home/visapros/public_html /home/visaquer/public_ht                                                                                        ml /home/visarank/public_html /home/visaratg/public_html /home/visarefe/public_h                                                                                        tml /home/visarefu/public_html /home/visaregu/public_html /home/visarest/public                                                                                        html /home/visasche/public_html /home/visasea/public_html /home/visashin/public                                                                                        html /home/visaspid/public_html /home/visastat/public_html /home/visasubm/public                                                                                        html /home/visasub/public_html /home/visasumm/public_html /home/visasum/public                                                                                        html /home/visateac/public_html /home/visatech/public_html /home/visateni/public                                                                                        _html /home/visathin/public_html /home/visatomo/public_html /home/visatran/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/visatuto/public_html /home/visauplo/public_html /home/visavali/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/visaweb/public_html /home/visaweek/public_html /home/visawifi/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/visaword/public_html /home/visawrit/public_html /home/visitevi/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/vrequire/public_html /home/vsecreta/public_html /home/vsecret/pub                                                                                        lic_html /home/vsites/public_html /home/vstand/public_html /home/vstateme/public                                                                                        _html /home/vstcheck/public_html /home/vsummit/public_html /home/walimuha/public                                                                                        _html /home/weldervi/public_html /home/workagen/public_html /home/workage/public                                                                                        _html /home/workappo/public_html /home/workdocu/public_html /home/workfees/publi                                                                                        c_html /home/workform/public_html /home/workperm/public_html /home/workpric/publ                                                                                        ic_html /home/worldbes/public_html /home/worldnew/public_html /home/zuricht/publ                                                                                        ic_html -type d
`


It's probably just sitting and churning the disk as it's looking through every subdir of every user's public_html dir and concatenates them into a big string?

yes but after it find the directories it does not go to next command and just sits right there nor it gives any error or stop the script

This might help: How to debug a bash script?

Dear brother Cyrus, i checked the script and shellcheck.com and it said "No issued detected"
Second iam using "bash -x rundirectories.sh" this command to execute the script....but still it hangs on -type d, and the log file is also empty....where as if i run the php artisan commands manually then they execute fine..but cleaning 400 folders one by one is very time consuming

You said log file is empty, it should at least contain "Starting cache clearing process...".

sorry....except this line...there is nothing in it and the file size is 34 bytes only

what happens if you run the find against a subset of directories, eg, find /home/a*/public_html or find /home/anytime/public_html?  what happens if you remove the 2>/dev/null to see if the find command is generating any errors? alternatively, what happens if you run the find call manually at the command prompt and capture all output (stdout + stderr) to a log file, eg find /home/*/public_html -type d > find.log 2>&1; and fwiw, website_folders=$(find ...) is not populating an array but rather assigning one (very) long string to website_folders

dear brother i removed 2>/dev/null and then as per your directions i restricted the find to a*...it reported directories starting with a only and then the script run successfully,

what about running the full find command with 2>/dev/null removed?  better yet, to make review a little easier, you can route stdout and stderr to separate output files, eg, (at the command prompt) find /home/*/public_html -type d > find.stdout 2>find.stderr or in the script website_folders=$(find /home/*/public_html -type d 2>find.stderr)

The argument list of your find command is probably too long.

but if i chnage a* to b* or v* then it does not work...as a* had only listed 6 directories so it worked, where as v* listed 34 directories and b* listed 25 direcotries....so should i try to limit it to 10 directories ata time? and as your suggestion worked how can i mark it working answer

fwiw, I ran the following on my system (Ubuntu 22.04, bash v5.1.16, find v4.8.0): mkdir -p home/user{0001..5000}/public_html/dir{1..5} and x=$(find home/*/public_html -type d 2>find.stderr); results: find.stderr is empty and x is assigned a string with 30,000 directory names

i also ran the script with adding 2>find.stderr....the said file is empty, the script halt at type d, and log file is at starting cache clearing process

Btw.: website_folders is a string and no array. This means that you will have problems with file or directory names that contain spaces during further processing.

brother...i have 409 folders and none of the folder contains spaces....all are 8 alphabet names and few have digits like 24 in the end and these are the commands which i basicaaly want to run on all folders echo "Clearing application cache..."
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan event:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
        } >> "$log_file" 2>&1


To create an array with all public_html folders just use: website_folders=( /home/*/public_html )

website_folders=( /home/*/public_html ) ended the script in just first folder

@HarisDurrani You have to iterate over the array with "${website_folders[@]}" instead of splitting and iterating over words with $website_folders.

Cyprus bro you asnwer was perfect and started working...where did it go...u did not let me to mark it as an answer....
